# Proving the existence of the Euler line using methods from Coordinate Geometry.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

I saw a [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry-home/triangle-properties/triangle-property-review/v/euler-s-line-proof) by Salman Khan, in which he gave a proof of existence of the **Euler Line**. He proved that the *circumcenter*, *orthocenter* and *centroid* of a triangle are *collinear*, and used normal geometry to do this. My background is in coordinate geometry, and I want to prove that the Euler line exists, using only methods from coordinate geometry, such as the `distance between points` formula, the `section formulae` (internal division), the `perpendicular bisector formula`, `centroid formula` and so on. For this, I need to know the coordinates of the *circumcenter* and the *orthocenter*, since the coordinates for the centroid are very easy to find and are given by the `centroid formula`.

So, if I consider a triangle $ABC$ with $A \equiv (x_1, y_1)$, $B \equiv (x_2, y_2)$ and $C \equiv (x_3, y_3)$ coordinates then by using the *centroid formula* I can find out that the x-coordinate (abscissa) and the y-coordinate (ordinate) of the centroid are following repectively:  $$\left(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}, \frac{y_1+y_2+y_3}{3}\right) $$ Let's denote the centroid of the triangle $D$.

Now, using perpendicular bisector formula, with some easy steps I got that the coordinates of the circumcenter of the triangle are the followings: $$\left(\frac{-\frac{1}{2}(x_2^{2}+y_2^{2}-x_3^{2}-y_3^{2})(y_1-y_2)+\frac{1}{2}(x_1^{2}+y_1^{2}-x_2^{2}-y_2^{2})(y_2-y_3)}{(x_1-x_2)(y_2-y_3)-(x_2-x_3)(y_1-y_2)}, \frac{-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^{2}+y_1^{2}-x_2^{2}-y_2^{2})(x_2-x_3)+\frac{1}{2}(x_2^{2}+y_2^{2}-x_3^{2}-y_3^{2})(x_1-x_2)}{(x_1-x_2)(y_2-y_3)-(x_2-x_3)(y_1-y_2)}\right) $$
Let's denote the circumcenter of the triangle $E$.

Then finding the equations of the altitudes of triangle $ABC$, I found out again with some easy steps, that the coordinates of the orthocenter of the triangle are the followings:
$$\left(\frac{(y_2-y_1)\{y_1(y_3-y_2)+x_1(x_3-x_2)\}-(y_3-y_2)\{y_3(y_2-y_1)+x_3(x_2-x_1)\}}{(x_2-x_3)(y_1-y_2)-(x_1-x_2)(y_2-y_3)}, \frac{(x_3-x_2)\{y_3(y_2-y_1)+x_3(x_2-x_1)\}-(x_2-x_1)\{y_1(y_3-y_2)+x_1(x_3-x_2)\}}{(x_2-x_3)(y_1-y_2)-(x_1-x_2)(y_2-y_3)}\right)$$

Let's denote the orthocenter of the triangle $F$.

As you can see, The *circumcenter* and *orthocenter* has very difficult coordinates in formation which I tried but can not be simplified any further. As you've already seen, to find from coordinate geometry, I need to solve simultaneous equations to find the intersection of two lines whose equations I got from using the vertices of the triangles, and this leads to a this very complicated Cartesian form of coordinates. As part of my textbook, I need to prove that the orthocenter, centroid and circumcenter is collinear and if I denote those points respectively as $F, D, E$ then prove that the ratio of the line segment $FD$ to $DE$ is $2$ to $1$. That is $$\frac{FD}{DE}=\frac{2}{1}$$

This is basically the gist of the **Euler's Line Theorem**. I know that the circumcenter of a triangle is the orthocenter of the medial triangle, but this is not helpful for me, maybe you can see why.

[One online resource](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-formula-for-circumcentre) for "*What is the formula for circumcentre?*" if that helps but sadly no one gives an explicit formula using only the coordinates of the vertices.

### Help:

Can someone provide a proof of the fact that the *circumcenter, centriod* and *orthocenter* are **collinear**? And using my coordinates of the *Circumcenter, Orthocenter and Centroid* using section formula can you prove that **$FD : DE = 2:1$** from there?

> I have been struggling with this, so I would be grateful if someone
> help me work it out.

---

Links:

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry-home/triangle-properties/triangle-property-review/v/euler-s-line-proof

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-formula-for-circumcentre

Comment: This is brilliant, let's hope that someone can help with this, I think there is a possibility, due to the elementary nature of the question, of getting a good answer.+1

Comment: Since you've gone through the trouble of calculating coordinates, and you know what you're trying to show, work towards that goal: Calculate $D-F$ and $E-D$. Don't bother making either of them particularly *pretty*; you just want to get to the point where you can convince yourself that the former is twice the latter. This'll prove collinearity (by effectively demonstrating that $FD$ and $DE$ have the same slope) as well as the desired $2:1$ ratio in the lengths.

Comment: @Blue, Yes, I thought about doing that. Since, if $D, E, F$ is collinear then the slope of $DF$ and $ED$ should be the same. I also have some idea how the slope might look like from the wikipedia page, the paragraph *Slope*. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line). But I am a little bit afraid to prove $FD:DE=2:1$ since here I have to use the section formulae. Is there any more easier way?

Comment: @Blue, it would be great, if you show me the steps that I have to go through. If you don't have time to write it down to LaTex format, write it down on the paper with pen, then post an image answer :).

Comment: @NazmulHasanShipon: This is the kind of thing I'd drop into a computer algebra system to symbol-bash for me. :)  That said, a manual approach isn't *terrible*; after all, the complicated denominators already match. One way to reduce the work is to assume convenient coords; say, $x_1=y_1=y_2=0$. ... As for proving the ratio ... To show $D-F=2(E-D)$ is to show $D_x-F_x=2(E_x-D_x)$ and $D_y-F_y=2(E_y-D_y)$; but, then, "obviously", $$|DF|^2=(D_x-F_x)^2+(D_y-F_y)^2=4((E_x-D_x)^2+(E_y-D_y)^2)=4|ED|^2$$ so you get $|DF|:|ED|=2:1$ for free. (That's actually a similar triangles argument in disguise.)

Comment: I can verify that with these formulas for $E$ and $F$, $\frac23E + \frac13F$ does simplify to $D$, as intended. (That is, there's no mistake in the formulas.) But I just did that with Mathematica.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, thank you for verifying that. But can you give me any algebraic proof of that?

Comment: Theoretically you could expand out $\frac23 E + \frac13F$ and check, but I admit that I don't want to do that.

Comment: Taking centroid $D=(0,0)$ at the origin and $A=(x_1,0)$ on the $x$-axis, we can let $B=(x_2,y_2)$ lie wherever it wants, and deduce that $C=-(A+B)=(-x_1-x_2,-y_2)$. Slogging through the coordinate algebra yields that the orthocenter and circumcenter are given by $F=\frac13P$ and $E =-\frac16P$, where $$P=\left(-\frac{x_1^2-2x_1x_2-2x_2^2-2y_2^2}{x_1},\frac{(x_1+2x_2)(2x_1^2-x_1x_2-x_2^2-y_2^2)}{x_1y_2}\right)$$ But then $F=-2E$, which says that $F$ is twice as far from the origin (aka, the centroid) as $E$, and in the opposite direction, proving both collinearity and the target ratio.

Comment: @Blue, have you missed a minus sign in $P$'s *y-coordinate*?

Comment: From the algebraic-geometry tag description: "This tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry." Please refrain from attaching that tag to this problem.

Comment: @NazmulHasanShipon: There's always a danger of me mis-transcribing something, but I've double-checked with *Mathematica*. All signs are correct.

Comment: @Blue, thank you for that small proof. At least, I can make progress with that _hoping_ someday someone would answer my question as I *expected* it to be.

Comment: @NazmulHasanShipon: To circle back from my "small proof" to my first comment ... If you calculate the coord differences, you'll find $F-D=\frac13P$ and $E-D=-\frac16P$ for a suitable $P$. This says exactly that $F-D=-2(E-D)$; ie, $F$ is twice the distance from $D$ as $E$, and in the opposite direction, proving both collinearity and the target ratio. Done. ... The only thing the "small proof" does is assume convenient coords, a perfectly valid way to proceed as there is "obviously" a way to move an arbitrary triangle into the convenient position. ... Anyway, I'm *hoping* this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

we have to prove that $r_{x}=r_{y}$ where

$\begin{array}{} r_{x}=\frac{x_{F}-x_{D}}{x_{D}-x_{E}} & r_{y}=\frac{y_{F}-y_{D}}{y_{D}-y_{E}}  \end{array}$

coordinates (x,y) of centroid(D), circumcenter(E) and orthocenter(F) as determinants. To get $y_{D}$, $y_{E}$ and $y_{F}$, exchange x for y in the formulas.

$x_{D}=\frac{x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}}{3}$

$x_{E}=\frac{1}{2·Det}·\left| \begin{array}{} x_{1}^2+y_{1}^2 & y_{1} & 1 \\ x_{2}^2+y_{2}^2 & y_{2} & 1 \\ x_{3}^2+y_{3}^2 & y_{3} & 1 \\ \end{array} \right|$

$x_{F}=\frac{1}{Det}(\left| \begin{array}{} x_{1} & x_{1}·y_{1} & 1 \\ x_{2} & x_{2}·y_{2} & 1 \\ x_{3} & x_{3}·y_{3} & 1 \\ \end{array} \right|+\left| \begin{array}{} y_{1} & y_{1}^{2} & 1 \\ y_{2} & y_{2}^2 & 1 \\ y_{3} & y_{3}^2 & 1 \\ \end{array} \right|  )$

$Det=\left| \begin{array}{} x_{1} & y_{1} & 1 \\ x_{2} & y_{2} & 1 \\ x_{3} & y_{3} & 1 \\ \end{array} \right|$

substituting, multiplying by $6.Det$, we get

$r_{x}=\frac{2·[3·(\left| \begin{array}{} x_{1} & x_{1}·y_{1} & 1 \\ x_{2} & x_{2}·y_{2} & 1 \\ x_{3} & x_{3}·y_{3} & 1 \\ \end{array} \right|+\left| \begin{array}{} y_{1} & y_{1}^{2} & 1 \\ y_{B} & y_{2}^2 & 1 \\ y_{3} & y_{3}^2 & 1 \\ \end{array} \right|  )-\left| \begin{array}{} x_{1} & y_{1} & 1 \\ x_{2} & y_{2} & 1 \\ x_{3} & y_{3} & 1 \\ \end{array} \right|·(x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}) ]}{2·\left| \begin{array}{} x_{1} & y_{1} & 1 \\ x_{2} & y_{2} & 1 \\ x_{3} & y_{3} & 1 \\ \end{array} \right|·(x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}) -3·\left| \begin{array}{} x_{1}^2+y_{1}^2 & y_{1} & 1 \\ x_{2}^2+y_{2}^2 & y_{2} & 1 \\ x_{3}^2+y_{3}^2 & y_{3} & 1 \\ \end{array} \right| }$

simplify, thirty-six terms (18 in the numerator and 18 in the denominator): $r_{x}=2$

By analogy: $r_{y}=2$ (as it's just replacing x by y) we get the same result from $r_{x}$ to $r_{y}$.

Comment: It's quite nice the way you did it. But as I get it $r_x=r_y$ proves only collinearity but what about the target ratio? And how did you solve  $r_x=2$? And how did you write $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}$ in this $(x_{1} ~~~ x_{2} ~~~ x_{3})$ form?

Comment: Thanks.I typed wrong. The correct one is $(x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3})$